# ¿Cómo muestro secciones de una lista?(python)

Tags: python, array, lista

No sé como hacer que se muestre por pantalla secciones de una lista(En este caso de hijos). Ya que por ejemplo a la familia A le corresponderían los hijos a, b,c y a la familia B los hijos d, e, f, g. Por lo que los hijos de familia A serían hasta hijos[2] y los siguientes de hijos[3] a hijos[5] y así sucesivamente para n familias y m hijos por familia.

````
hijos = []
canthijos = []

x = int(input("Introduzca numero de familias a ingresar: "))
for i in range(x):
    a = input("Introduzca nombre de familia: ")
    familia.append(a)
    b = int(input("Introduzca numero de hijos de familia: "))
    canthijos.append(b)
    for j in range(b):
        c = input("Introduzca nombre de hijo: ")
        hijos.append(c)

for m in range(len(familia)):
    print(familia[m])
    for w in range(canthijos[m]):
        print(hijos[w])


print(familia)
print(hijos)```
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ni listas, ni tuplas, son estructuras de datos adecuadas para lo que se solicita, ya que tienen una indexación numérica, difícilmente controlable por el usuario. Para estos casos, lo más cómodo sería usar [diccionarios](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries), los cuales se tienen una indexación personalizada; se comportan similar a un xml o json. Un ejemplo conceptual puede ser:

```
var = {
    item1 => subitem1 => elem1,
             subitem2 => [elem2, elem3...],
             subitem3 => subsubitem1 => [elem4, elem5...],
                         subsubitem2 => [elem5, elem6...],
                         ...etc
             ...etc
    item2 => subitem1 => elem7,
             subitem2 => [elem8, elem9...],
             subitem3 => subsubitem1 => [elem10, elem11...],
                         subsubitem2 => [elem12, elem13...],
                         ...etc
             ...etc
    ...etc
}
```

Aplicando el concepto a tu problema, yo propondría que el diccionario quede algo así, por ejemplo:

```
familias = {
'perez':{'conyuges':['Juan', 'Maria'], 'hijos':['marta', 'pedro', 'pablo']}, 
'lopez':{'conyuges':['Ana', 'Luisa'], 'hijos':['firulais']}
}
```

Si quieres agregar otra familia

```
familias['gonzalez'] = {'conyuges':['Carlos', 'Rosa'], 'hijos':[]}
```

Si quieres agregar un hijo a la famila gonzalez:

```
familias['gonzalez']['hijos'].append('Maria')
```

Imprimir los conyuges de la familia 'perez' (en forma de lista)

```
print(familias['perez']['conyuges'])
# ['Juan', 'Maria']
```

Listar los hijos de todas las familias en forma de texto:

```
for fnombre, fvalor in familias.items():
    hijos = ', '.join(fvalor['hijos']) # Convierte lista a texto
    print(f'Familia {fnombre} -> Hijos: {hijos}')
```

Resultado:

```
Familia perez -> Hijos: marta, pedro, pablo
Familia lopez -> Hijos: firulais
Familia gonzalez -> Hijos: Maria
```

[NOTA] En un sistema de la vida real, lo que debe ser es que cada familia tenga un índice único (`key`) o código que representa a toda la entidad, y en el `valor` va la información, algo así:

```
'f1353' : {'nombre':'perez', 'conyuges':['Juan', 'Maria'], 'hijos'['marta', ...], etc}
```

Esto es así porque un índice como `perez` es altamente probable que se se repita con otra familia.

Comment: En mi país tienes el RUN (Rol Unico Nacional) desde el nacimiento. Es tu identificador único para toda la vida y es la llave que usa el gobierno, el comercio y las instituciones para identificarte. Supongo que será lo mismo en otros paises.